# How to seach emoji with proper text via Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here is my code:

```
var emoji = "⭐";
var query = myContext.Products.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(emoji));

var queryString = query.ToQueryString();
var list = query.ToList();
```

Query returns all table records. If I replace contains to equal works great, but I have to search something like this:

```
"this is my emoji ⭐"
```

This is the SQL query:

```
 DECLARE @__emoji_0 nvarchar(4000) = N'⭐'

 SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Name], [p].[Quantity] 
 FROM [Products] AS [p]
 WHERE (@__emoji_0 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__emoji_0, [p].[Name]) > 0)
```

Is any way to do this in EF Core or raw SQL?

Comment: Is that the specific character you're looking for? "White Medium Star", [U+2B50](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2B50), isn't an emoji character as such because it's in the Basic Multilingual Plane, so it should match using either `N'⭐'` or `nchar(11088)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is the fact that emojis and strings are represented differently.

Before you can search the emojis you will need to decide how are you gonna unify them both in search query and db.

First of all emojis are a pair of chars.What does that mean? Here as a quote from the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding-introduction):

```
"".Length = 2
s[0] = '�' ('\ud83d')
s[1] = '�' ('\udc02')
```

> These examples show that the value of string.Length, which indicates the number of char instances, doesn't necessarily indicate the number of displayed characters. A single char instance by itself doesn't necessarily represent a character.

The char pairs that map to a single character are called surrogate pairs. To understand how they work, you need to understand Unicode and UTF-16 encoding.

Having this in mind I would go as follows:

1. Define a method which will convert emojis to a UTF16 string[] which will keep the two surrogate chars representation.

   ```
   internal static string[] EmojiToUtf16Pair(string emoji)
   {
       string[] arr = new string[2];
       for (int i = 0; i < emoji.Length; i++)
       {
           arr[i] = emoji[i].ToString();
       }

       return arr;

   }
   ```

This could be use when you persist emojis in DB. Depending on how you decide to persist the emojis in DB some modification could be done for that method e.g. to return concatenated string or something like that.

2. I am not sure when, but for some reason you could use another method to do the reverse operation -> UTF16 to Emoji

   ```
    internal static string UTF16PairToEmoji(string[] codes)
    {
        var test = string.Empty;
        foreach (var i in codes)
        {
            test += i;
        }

        var result = test.ToString();

        return result;
    }
   ```

Here is all the code example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        var str = "";
        var utf16 = string.Join("",EmojiToUtf16Pair(str));

        Console.WriteLine(utf16);

        var testEmpoji = UTF16PairToEmoji(EmojiToUtf16Pair(str));

        Console.WriteLine(testEmpoji);
    }


    internal static string[] EmojiToUtf16Pair(string emoji)
    {
        string[] arr = new string[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < emoji.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = emoji[i].ToString();
        }

        return arr;

    }

    internal static string UTF16PairToEmoji(string[] codes)
    {
        var test = string.Empty;
        foreach (var i in codes)
        {
            test += i;
        }

        var result = test.ToString();

        return result;
    }
}
```

[emoji](/questions/tagged/emoji) [ef-core](/questions/tagged/ef-core) [db-query](/questions/tagged/db-query)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like command

```
SELECT * FROM emoticon where emoji_utf like '';
```

with EF in .net core

```
Emoticon emoticon=db_context.Emoticons.Where(a=>EF.Functions.Like(a.EmojiUtf,"%"+item.emojiString+"%" ) ).FirstOrDefault();
```